# swf or movieclip to flv or avi?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

I'm looking for a library that allows you to export you flash based animation (possible bitmap) into flv or video format. I remember something like this existed, but I've lost the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the movie as Quicktime and then use a video utility to convert it.

**File > Export > Export Movie**

http://blog.kazumakzak.com/2008/12/10/export-scripted-flash-animation-to-quicktime/

Comment: I don't mean in compile time. on run time, like how you can have slides show that you can make in flash (runtime) but export to youtube

Comment: Export Movie can simulate you running the SWF with scripts handling whatever you want. Check the third step in the link i posted.

Comment: hmm interesting, this may be useful, but the problem is that I won't know how long the movie will be at compile time, I was hoping for a serverside script that would convert .swf to .avi or flv

Comment: You could use the "Stop exporting when last frame is reached" option. If you don´t have a plain timeline you could add an empty frame in the main timeline and code the SWF to go to that frame whenever your code is complete.